# Run a simulation many times using Different Parameters in NS2

Tags: tcl, simulation, ns2

Help Please; 
I have this code in NS2

```
#call
source test1.tcl
for { set a 5} { $a <10} { incr a } {
input_Protocol_pramerters 20 $a 2.0 $a
}
puts "Done"
```

in each iteration, I need different output tracefile.
When I run this code
I got the error after iteration 1

The test1.tcl include all simulation setup for NS2 Scenario using DSR protocol

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in the code... besides that, I can't say much.

Comment: If you can't do it any other way, run your overall code many times and capture traces in different files each time. Look in your code for where the name of the trace file is set…

Comment: I need to run the code 10000 times to make optimization for the overall traces files. it is infeasible to run manually. The test1.tcl is work fine for one time individually